# Android Flutter launch custom activity with cached engine

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, caching, flutter-engine

Iam integrating `FlutterActivity` to a native Android app.
I have `CustomFlutterActivity` which inherits from `FlutterActivity`, which I want to launch using cached `FlutterEngine`.

This is the code from the documentation for how to do this:

```
startActivity(
      FlutterActivity
        .withNewEngine()
        .build(currentActivity)
      );
```

What I want to achieve is to launch my `CustomFlutterActivity` with my cached engine (and not a generic `FlutterActivity` as the documentation says)

Answer (score 3):

In your `CustomFlutterActivity` which I suppose is derived from `FlutterActivity` you can override `getCachedEngineId` and provide the `my_engine_id` you have previously cached according to the docs, namely:

```
FlutterEngineCache
      .getInstance()
      .put("my_engine_id", flutterEngine);
```

Thus:

```
class CustomFlutterActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun getCachedEngineId(): String? {
        return "my_engine_id"
    }
}
```

See [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You can override `provideFlutterEngine` and return `FlutterEngine` from the cache.

```
class CustomFlutterActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun provideFlutterEngine(context: Context): FlutterEngine? {
        return FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get("flutter_engine")
    }
}
```